# What does the first value returned from tf.metrics.accuracy represent

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'd like to understand the values returned from `tf.metrics.accuracy`

Consider this minimal example:

```
predictions = tf.constant([[1,0,1], [1,0,1]], dtype=tf.int32)
labels = tf.constant([[0,0,1], [1,0,1]], dtype=tf.int32)

acc = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels, predictions)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
  res = sess.run(acc)
print(res)
```

which outputs:

```
(0.0, 0.8333333)
```

The second value is what I'd expect (we have 5/6 values where `predictions == labels` so 5/6 ~= 0.83) but the first zero value is a mystery to me?

The [TensorFlow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/accuracy) have this to say:

> Returns:
>
> - accuracy: A Tensor representing the accuracy, the value of
>     total divided by count.
> - update_op: An operation that increments the
>     total and count variables appropriately and whose value matches
>     accuracy.

but this suggests that both return ops should have value of 0.83, no? (but then what would be the point of returning 2 ops?!)

Feel like I am missing something fundamental!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on tensorflow code and the description, first value is the accuracy computed without the latest batch of data (in case of streaming data) and the second value is the final accuracy computed with all the data. This is used by tensorflow for stream processing of data.